# Add Height and Width through jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am working in jQuery script.But a little bit problem i want add the width tag and height tag in image .

how to do it??

Comment: You should check the documentation of jQuery for such basic questions. Currently, the first result for "jquery height" in the most common search engines is http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred way is to use the [`css` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$('#yourImgID').css({ width: '300px', height: '150px' });
```

If you must specifically add the `width` and `height` attributes to the `<img>` element, replace the `css` method with the [`attr` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('#yourImgID').attr({ width: '300px', height: '150px' });
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$('#idofimg').prop('width','value');
```

or

```
$('#idofimg').css('width','value');
```

or maybe even

```
$('#idofimg').width('value');
```

Comment: ohoho thanks sir.i will use that code.

Comment: @OnlyPritesh just to clarify - you said in your question you want to "add" the height tag and width tag - are you talking about setting the property or mathematics ? ie add the 2 values together ?

Answer (score 3):

Something like: `$('#img_id').attr('width', 100).attr('height', 50);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').attr('height',25);
$('img').attr('width',25);
```